# How would I check if a Rect I have drawn on a JPanel has been clicked?

Tags: java, graphics, 2d

How would I go about checking if any of the Rects I've drawn (or filled, if you will) with my drawChessSquare() method have been clicked? I have tried looking into the processMouseEvent() method but I'm not sure how I would get that to work. For your information, it currently prints out an 8x8 chessboard, and repaints it in an update method, which is run in a while loop in a separate main class. GitHub here just in case you need to look closer: https://github.com/ewanh26/Chess This is my code:

````
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class Board extends JFrame {

    public static int WIDTH;
    public static int HEIGHT;

    public Board(int WIDTH, int HEIGHT, String TITLE) {
        super(TITLE);

        Board.WIDTH = WIDTH;
        Board.HEIGHT = HEIGHT;

        setBackground(Color.black);
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        contentPane.add(new Checker());
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void update() {
        repaint();
    }

    static class Checker extends JPanel {

        private final Dimension preferredSize = new Dimension(Board.WIDTH, Board.HEIGHT);

        private void drawChessSquare(int w, int h, int x, int y, Graphics g, Color color) {
            g.setColor(color);
            g.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return preferredSize;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            boolean black = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
                int x = 0;
                int y = 0;

                if (i < 8) {
                    assert true;
                } else if (i < 8 * 2) {
                    y = Board.HEIGHT / 8;
                } else if (i < 8 * 3) {
                    y = (Board.HEIGHT / 8) * 2;
                } else if (i < 8 * 4) {
                    y = (Board.HEIGHT / 8) * 3;
                } else if (i < 8 * 5) {
                    y = (Board.HEIGHT / 8) * 4;
                } else if (i < 8 * 6) {
                    y = (Board.HEIGHT / 8) * 5;
                } else if (i < 8 * 7) {
                    y = (Board.HEIGHT / 8) * 6;
                } else {
                    y = (Board.HEIGHT / 8) * 7;
                }

                if (i % 8 == 0) {
                    assert true;
                } else if (i == 1 || (i - 1) % 8 == 0) {
                    x = Board.WIDTH / 8;
                } else if (i == 2 || (i - 2) % 8 == 0) {
                    x = (Board.WIDTH / 8) * 2;
                } else if (i == 3 || (i - 3) % 8 == 0) {
                    x = (Board.WIDTH / 8) * 3;
                } else if (i == 4 || (i - 4) % 8 == 0) {
                    x = (Board.WIDTH / 8) * 4;
                } else if (i == 5 || (i - 5) % 8 == 0) {
                    x = (Board.WIDTH / 8) * 5;
                } else if (i == 6 || (i - 6) % 8 == 0) {
                    x = (Board.WIDTH / 8) * 6;
                } else if (i == 7 || (i - 7) % 8 == 0) {
                    x = (Board.WIDTH / 8) * 7;
                }

                if (black) {
                    if (!((i-7) % 8 == 0)) black = !black;
                    drawChessSquare(Board.WIDTH / 8, Board.HEIGHT / 8, x, y, g, Color.black);
                } else {
                    if (!((i-7) % 8 == 0)) black = !black;
                    drawChessSquare(Board.WIDTH / 8, Board.HEIGHT / 8, x, y, g, Color.orange);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}```
````

Comment: Why not just use JLabels with GridLayout to make the board?

Comment: @DevilsHnd Could u maybe take me through how I'd do that please?

Comment: Sure....see the answer provided below.

Comment: You are very welcome.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a **heavily** commented runnable explaining one way you can do it. It also includes Mouse events that demonstrates a few things you can do. Remove the comments when you're done if you like....there is *waaaay* too much of it.

The demo displays text within each JLabel which indicates the name provided to that particular JLabel's name property during form creation. These names will most likely come in handy as your game development progresses.

In the image below, look at the title bar as each board square is clicked upon with the mouse pointer.

[image]

This demo utilizes an Array of JLabels and, as I'm sure you already know, you can add images to JLabels as well as set text, background and foreground colors, borders, etc. Of course you also have several different events for you to use. Ugggg...using JLabels for this sort of thing is just another option I suppose. Try it, play with it for a while and see what you think.

Here is the runnable code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class ChessBoardDemo extends JFrame {

    private JLabel[] boardLabel;
    private int gridWidth = 8;   // X axis (horizintal)
    private int gridHeight = 8;  // Y axis (vertical)
    private int squarePixelSize = 50;  // 50 x 50 pixels.
    
    private Color hoverColor = Color.decode("#DDCCFF");
    private Color beforeHoverColor;
    private Color borderColor = Color.WHITE;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                 new ChessBoardDemo().startApp(args);
            }
        });
    }

    private void startApp(String[] args) {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(gridHeight, gridWidth));
    
        // Setup the Board Squares (JLabels)
        // Create an Array of JLabels
        boardLabel = new JLabel[gridWidth * gridHeight];
        MouseHandler mouseHandler = new MouseHandler();
        /* Each JLabel will have a name set into the Name property.
           These names will come in handy at some point during 
           development. Rows are designated from A to H and columns 
           are designated as 1 to 8 (for an 8 by 8 grid for example).  */
        int labelNameAsciiStartLetter = 65; // A
        // A Flag used to stagger the colors as in a checkers or chess board.
        boolean stagger = false;
        /* Will hold the background color for each JLabel square as the board 
           is generated.    */
        Color squareColor;
        // Counter used for applying the proper name value to each JLabel Square.
        int columnCounter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < boardLabel.length; i++) {
            // Is the value in i an even number? (0 is considered an even number here).
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                /* Yes... then color the JLabel backgound red unless 
                   stagger is true in which case turn it black. Ternary
                   Operator is used here.                */
                squareColor = !stagger ? Color.RED : Color.BLACK;
            }
            else {
                /* NO... then color the JLabel backgound black unless 
                   stagger is true in which case turn it red. Ternary
                   Operator is used here.                */
                squareColor = !stagger ? Color.BLACK : Color.RED;
            }
            //Increment the column counter.
            columnCounter++;  
            // Make this array element a new JLabel.
            boardLabel[i] = new JLabel(); 
            // Designate the appropreate name to its' name property.
            boardLabel[i].setName(Character.toString((char)labelNameAsciiStartLetter) 
                               + String.valueOf(columnCounter));
            /* Set the foreground text color. You most likely don't 
               want the text anyways. It's just here for demo. */
            boardLabel[i].setForeground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
            /* Set the text Horizontal alignmemnt. You most likely
               don't want the text anyways. It's just here for demo. */
            boardLabel[i].setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            /* Set the text in JLabel. You most likely don't want 
               the text anyways. It's just here for demo. */
            boardLabel[i].setText(boardLabel[i].getName());
            // Set the JLabel as opaque so as to see the background color. 
            boardLabel[i].setOpaque(true);
            // If you want a border around each square then un-comment the next line.
            //boardLabels[i].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY, 1));
            // Set the current JLabel backgound color.
            boardLabel[i].setBackground(squareColor);
            // Set the current JLabel size (in pixels).
            boardLabel[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(squarePixelSize, squarePixelSize));
            boardLabel[i].addMouseListener(mouseHandler);
            getContentPane().add(boardLabel[i]);
            // If we reached our grid width...
            if (columnCounter == gridWidth) {
                // Toggle the stagger flag to its oposite. False to true or true to false.
                stagger = !stagger; 
                // Increment to the next ASCII letter code (ex: 65 [A] to 66 [B] etc).
                labelNameAsciiStartLetter++; 
                // Reset the column counter to 0 in prep for next row.
                columnCounter = 0; 
            }
        }
        // Let the layout manager setup all the components in proper order.
        pack();
        // Make the JFrame form visible.
        setVisible(true);
        // Place the form at center screen (must be after setVisible).
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    
    }

    /* Mouse Handler inner class to to take care of the mouse events
       for all the JLabels that make up the board.    */
    private class MouseHandler extends MouseAdapter {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) {
            // Get the JLabel that the mouse was clicked on.
            JLabel source = (JLabel) evt.getSource();
            // Indicate it in the JFrame Title Bar.
            setTitle("You clicked on  the JLabel named: " + source.getName());
        }
    
        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent evt) {
            // When the mouse pointer enters a JLabel's boundry...
            // Get the JLabel that the mouse pointer has entered on.
            JLabel label = (JLabel) evt.getSource();
            // Get its' current backgound color.
            beforeHoverColor = label.getBackground();
            /* Un-comment the following line if you want to 
               change the backgound color on mouse hover.  */
            //label.setBackground(hoverColor);
            // Place a border around the JLabel the mouse is hovering over.
            label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(borderColor, 1));
        }
    
        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent evt) {
            // When the mouse pointer exits a JLabel's boundry...
            // Get the JLabel that the mouse pointer has exited from.
            JLabel label = (JLabel) evt.getSource();
            /* Un-comment the following line if you want to 
               change the JLabel backgound color to its original
               state when mouse leaves the JLabel.     */
            //label.setBackground(beforeHoverColor);
            /* Remove the border from around the JLabel when the 
               mouse pointer exits.     */
            label.setBorder(null);
        }
    }

}
```